# Firebase orderBy timestamp not actually ordering

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query that orders by my timestamp value in my server, the currently timestamp is set by my pojo as a date

```
data class Timestamp(@ServerTimestamp val timestamp:Date? = null)
```

This timestamp is place in firestore as

[image]

But when I do my fetch code

```
 val snapshot =  FirebaseFirestore
            .getInstance()
            .collection("orders")
            .whereEqualTo("uid",currentUser.uid)
            .whereLessThan("status",Status.DELIVERED.statusNumber)
            .orderBy("status",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .orderBy("timestamp",Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
```

I want to see first on the list the latest orders I did, but instead , is mixing my old orders with the new ones, my goal here is to bring up first the newest orders I placed inside orders collection, but instead it does not order it when new orders are created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want newest documents first, you should do a DESCENDING order on timestamp.  If you want the list to be primarily sorted by timestamp, and secondarily sorted by status, the timestamp orderBy it should come before the orderBy on status (right now, you are sorting primarily on status and secondarily on timestamp).

```
.orderBy("timestamp",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
.orderBy("status",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
```

Comment: is not possible: ** java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query. You have an inequality where filter (whereLessThan(), whereGreaterThan(), etc.) on field 'status' and so you must also have 'status' as your first orderBy() field, but your first orderBy() is currently on field 'timestamp' instead.**

Comment: I have already tried in the past to change the orderBy but I cant

Comment: Then you will have to sort the records by timstamp on the client.  That shouldn't be hard.

Comment: well, I was expecting firestore to handle the query, not the client, thats weird, thanks doug